# How to build model with description in swagger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, swagger-ui

I want to build model with description in swagger like in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CwSK.png) [[json]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDnNQ.png) and i have something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gv7o.png). I want to have description title and data inside block. Here is code:

```
require 'swagger_helper'
describe 'Users API' do
  path '/register/first_step' do
    post 'First step of Registration' do
      tags 'registration'
      consumes 'application/json', 'application/xml'
      parameter name: :user, in: :body, schema: {
          type: :object,
          properties: {
              first_name: {   
              properties: 
              {
                  type: :string,
                  id: :integer
              }    
                },
          }, required: [ :first_name ]
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how the actual user JSON supposed to look like?

Comment: I uploaded picture

Answer (score 0):

If you want only string `first_name` for `user` object, then it should be:

```
parameter name: :user, in: :body, schema: {
  type: :object,
  required: [:first_name],
  properties: {
    first_name: { type: :string }      
  }
}
```